# Callback function is not working on click properly

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to call functions while I click on my datepicker so that I can change my graph dynamically according to the input dates I have given.so below is my part of the code for my datepicker

```
<div id="reportrange" style="background: #fff; cursor: pointer; padding: 5px 10px; border: 1px solid #ccc; width: 100%">
<i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>&nbsp;
<span></span> <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
</div>
```

Below is my script

```
<script>

$(function() {
var start = moment().subtract(6, 'days');
var end = moment();

$('#reportrange').daterangepicker.ranges.on({click:function () 
{
    addtoday()

}
});
function cb(start, end) {
    $('#reportrange span').html(start.format('MMMM D, YYYY') + ' - ' + end.format('MMMM D, YYYY'));

}

$('#reportrange').daterangepicker({
    startDate: start,
    endDate: end,
    minDate: '-1Y',
    maxDate:new Date(),
    ranges: {
       'Today': [moment(), moment(),],
       'Yesterday': [moment().subtract(1, 'days'), moment().subtract(1, 'days'),addyesterday()],
       'Last 7 Days': [moment().subtract(6, 'days'), moment()],
       'Last 30 Days': [moment().subtract(29, 'days'), moment()],
       'This Month': [moment().startOf('month'), moment().endOf('month')],
       'Last Month': [moment().subtract(1, 'month').startOf('month'), moment().subtract(1, 'month').endOf('month')],
    },
}, cb);
cb(start, end);

});
```

When I click on ranges 'Today' I have to update my chart for today that is the function addtoday()

Below is a function which I have to call

```
function addData1() {
    let abc = [{% for item in values1 %}
        {{item}},
    {% endfor %}]
    mixedChart.data.datasets[1].data = abc;
    mixedChart.update();
}
```

Comment: same like addData1() i have a function addtoday()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this..

```
$('#date-range0')
  .dateRangePicker().bind('datepicker-change',function(event,obj){
    /* This event will be triggered when second date is selected */
        console.log(obj);
        });
```

---Updated ----

```
$('#reportrange').daterangepicker({
    startDate: start,
    endDate: end,
    minDate: '-1Y',
    maxDate:new Date(),
    ranges: {
       'Today': [moment(), moment(),],
       'Yesterday': [moment().subtract(1, 'days'), moment().subtract(1, 'days'),addyesterday()],
       'Last 7 Days': [moment().subtract(6, 'days'), moment()],
       'Last 30 Days': [moment().subtract(29, 'days'), moment()],
       'This Month': [moment().startOf('month'), moment().endOf('month')],
       'Last Month': [moment().subtract(1, 'month').startOf('month'), moment().subtract(1, 'month').endOf('month')],
    },
}, cb).bind('datepicker-change',function(event,obj){
    addData1()
        })
```

Comment: Tried it but no result, I have also tried by calling the function inside ranges like

Comment: 'Today':[moment(),moment(),addtoday()].It worked but the problem its taking before i click on today

Comment: Where ever I insert this function in the code it's running, but the problem is after clicking on today this function should run

Comment: do you want to  trigger addtoday() function  when second date is selected?

Answer (score 0):

I got a partial answer@Sooriya Dasanayake. I can only execute one function when I apply,
But I want to change function when I apply differently the dates. Thanks a lot@Sooriya Dasanayake for your work but I am at the edge of getting the correct result

```
<script>

$(function() {
var start = moment().subtract(6, 'days');
var end = moment();


function cb(start, end) {
    $('#reportrange span').html(start.format('MMMM D, YYYY') + ' - ' + end.format('MMMM D, YYYY'));

}

$('#reportrange').daterangepicker({
    startDate: start,
    endDate: end,
    minDate: moment().subtract(365, 'days'),
    maxDate:moment(),
    ranges: {
       'Today': [moment(), moment(),],
       'Yesterday': [moment().subtract(1, 'days'), moment().subtract(1, 'days'),],
       'Last 7 Days': [moment().subtract(6, 'days'), moment()],
       'Last 30 Days': [moment().subtract(29, 'days'), moment()],
       'This Month': [moment().startOf('month'), moment().endOf('month')],
       'Last Month': [moment().subtract(1, 'month').startOf('month'), moment().subtract(1, 'month').endOf('month')],
    },
},

    cb);
cb(start, end);

});

 $('#reportrange').on('apply.daterangepicker', function() {
if(Today='Today')
    addtoday();
if(Yesterday='Yesterday')
   addyesterday();
if(lastweek='Last 7 Days')
   lastweek();
if(presentmonth='This Month')
   presentmonth();
if(any_date='Custom Range')
   any_date();
 });


 </script>
```